# Merge 2 data frames by the columns that do not match exactly

Tags: r, dataframe, fuzzyjoin

I have 2 data frames. I am trying to merge/join them together while specifying how I want rows to align. Mock data below.

```
df <- data.frame(Race = c("White", "NHPI", "AA"),
                 Cases = c(20, 4, 7)
                 )
df
> df
   Race Cases
1 White    20
2  NHPI     4
3    AA     7

df2 <- data.frame(Race2 = c("African American", "White", "Hawaiian or Pacific Islander"),
                  TotalPopulation = c(200, 400, 50))
df2
> df2
                         Race2 TotalPopulation
1             African American             200
2                        White             400
3 Hawaiian or Pacific Islander              50
```

What I would like to do is merge the data while specifying which row matches with the other dataset- for example, I want the merge to align "African American" and "AA". Ideal output would look like this-

```
   Race Cases                        Race2 TotalPopulation
1    AA     7             African American             200
2 White    20                        White             400
3  NHPI     4 Hawaiian or Pacific Islander              50
```

I am slightly newer to coding, so if you could walk through the code that would be great. Thanks so much.

Comment: What's the rule for merging? Let's say you also had `HL` in dataframe 1 and `Latino or Hispanic` in dataframe 2. How do you plan to tell "the computer" that those are a match? I think you need to create a cross-tab and manually match the values from `Race` in either dataframe, and use that as a key for merging.

Comment: Darn, that is what I was trying to avoid. I was hoping there was going to be a shortcut where I could specify row alignments. Thanks for the help.

Comment: See my answer below; keep in mind that you'd have to check your work to make sure everything is matched correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @M-- comment, you can do:

```
df %>%
  left_join(df2 %>% 
               mutate(Race = case_when(
                 Race2 == "African American" ~ "AA",
                 Race2 == "Hawaiian or Pacific Islander" ~ "NHPI",
                 .default = Race2
               )))

   Race Cases                        Race2 TotalPopulation
1 White    20                        White             400
2  NHPI     4 Hawaiian or Pacific Islander              50
3    AA     7             African American             200
```

If you can set full name and then extract abbreviations you can do it faster, however, note you have `NHPI` and `Hawaiian or Pacific Islander` and there is not match. If you can include N in `Hawaiian or Pacific Islander`, then you can use:

```
df %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% 
              mutate(Race = gsub("[:a-z:]*\\s*", "", Race2),
                     Race = sub("W", "White", Race)))
```

This work under the assumption of the df2 is as follows:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Race2 = c("African American", "White", "Naaaa Hawaiian or Pacific Islander"),
                  TotalPopulation = c(200, 400, 50))
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Would you mind if I ask what the gsub and sub piece of code are doing?

Comment: They are a kind of 'find and replace' function that allow regular expressions

Comment: @JilberUrbina we can use `powerjoin` to get closer to what OP is after, but it'd be very futile as I said. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt at matching the columns by the first letter of each `Race` name. As I said in my comment, matching these without any "human supervision" is error prone, so keep that in mind.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(powerjoin)
library(stringdist)

power_full_join(mutate(df1, Race_match = gsub("[^A-Z]", "", df1$Race)),
                mutate(df2, Race_match = gsub("[^A-Z]", "", df2$Race)), 
                           by = ~ stringdist(.x$Race_match, .y$Race_match) < 2) %>% 
  select(-contains("Race_match"))
#>    Race Cases                        Race2 TotalPopulation
#> 1 White    20                        White             400
#> 2  NHPI     4 Hawaiian or Pacific Islander              50
#> 3    AA     7             African American             200
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

##### Explanation:

Here, I am adding a column to each dataframe with the capital letters extracted from `Race` columns, using `dplyr::mutate`.

```
mutate(df1, Race_match = gsub("[^A-Z]", "", df1$Race))
#>    Race Cases Race_match
#> 1 White    20          W
#> 2  NHPI     4       NHPI
#> 3    AA     7         AA

mutate(df2, Race_match = gsub("[^A-Z]", "", df2$Race2))
#>                          Race2 TotalPopulation Race_match
#> 1             African American             200         AA
#> 2                        White             400          W
#> 3 Hawaiian or Pacific Islander              50        HPI
```

As you can see, `Race_match` columns are not a 1 to 1 match (see `HPI` and `NHPI`). But they are close enough (what do I mean by close enough?).

We can use `powerjoin` library along with `stringdist` to define where/how do we wanna join the dataframes. Here, I am joining the rows if the difference in `Race_match` columns is less than 2. So, that's what I considered close enough!

```
power_full_join(mutate(df1, Race_match = gsub("[^A-Z]", "", df1$Race)),
                mutate(df2, Race_match = gsub("[^A-Z]", "", df2$Race)), 
                           by = ~ stringdist(.x$Race_match, .y$Race_match) < 2)
#>    Race Cases Race_match.x                        Race2 TotalPopulation   Race_match.y
#> 1 White    20            W                        White             400     W
#> 2  NHPI     4         NHPI Hawaiian or Pacific Islander              50   HPI
#> 3    AA     7           AA             African American             200    AA
```

Lastly, I drop `Race_match` columns, using `dplyr::select`, as they were created just to help with the join.